# C++ - Variable Decrement

Tags: c++, function, variables, multidimensional-array, char

Heys.

I have this code, which sets a table for some mystery reason. Size is 6x60. Which means **SIZEY** defined as 6, and **SIZEX** as 60.

```
void set_table(char** table)
{
    int i,j,k=0;

    for(i=0;i<SIZEY;i+=3){
        for(j=0;j<SIZEX;j++){
            switch(k++%5){
                case 0:
                    table[i][j]='|';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    table[i][j]=' ';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    table[i][j]=(char)((((k-2)/50)%10)+48);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    table[i][j]=(char)((((k-3)/5)%10)+48);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    table[i][j]=' ';
                    break;
                default:
                    continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am doing this with 3 variables, as you can see. Question is, can i do that with 2 variables, or even with only 1 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @KirilKirov just wondering if that can be done with less source

Comment: @KirilKirov , sorry my bad i didn't read it properly.

Comment: Less is not always better. Sure you could do this with a single variable and do a bunch of mathematical operations to get your `j` and `k` indices, but the code would be pretty much unreadable. If you want the code to be clearer, use classes like `std::vector`, have a look at the `algorithm` header and make your code more self documenting.

Comment: @TartanLlama thanks for the tips captain!

Comment: You can do this with a single variable. But as TartanLlama already pointed out, it will be hard to read. And because of the multiplications and/or divisions required, the code will be much slower.

Comment: I recommend replacing `48` with `'0'`, as it will be a lot easier to read.

Comment: By the way, `case 2` and `case 3` are the same and evaluate to `table[i][j] = '0';`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplification for you:

```
    switch(k++%5){
        case 0:
            table[i][j]='|';
            break;
        case 1:
        case 4:
            table[i][j]=' ';
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
            table[i][j]= '0';
            break;
        default:
            continue;
  }
```

With C++, one case can *fall* into another, such as with cases 1 and 2 above.

Your expressions for case 2 and 3 can be simplified.  I'll use case 2 as an example:
`((((k-2)/50)%10)+48)`
Substituting 2 for k yields
`((((2-2)/50)%10)+48)`
Simplify:
`((((0)/50)%10)+48)`
Zero divided by anything is zero, simplifying again:
`(((0)%10)+48)`
Zero mod anything is zero, since it involves division:
`((0)+48)`
Simplifying:
`(48)`
Replacing with the equivalent character (since your array is `char`):
'0'